# Create Task in loop but all tasks take the same parameter

Tags: c#, task

I'm trying to create tasks in a loop and each task uses different values as method parameter. However, I found all tasks are having the same parameter

```
            for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(new Task( () => DownloadFunc(i) ));
        }

        WATCH.Reset();
        WATCH.Start();
        Parallel.ForEach(tasks, t => t.Start());
```

Comment: try storing the value of `i` in another variable and use that variable as the function parameter

Comment: @JonSkeet The behavior of a capture `for` loop variable has never changed in C#'s history.

Comment: @Servy: Doh, you're right, it was foreach, of course. Deleted the comment :)

Comment: There must be lots of duplicates for this question...

Comment: @JonSkeet Found one that you answered ;)

Comment: On an unrelated note, there's no reason to *start* a bunch of tasks in parallel.  Starting a task is *very* fast. It's slower to try to parallelize the loop than to just start the tasks in sequence.  Additionally, you shouldn't really ever create unstarted tasks in the first place.  Just use `Task.Run` to execute a function in a thread pool thread, rather than dealing with having unstarted tasks and starting them later.  It's just creating something that can go wrong or cause confusion without really adding value.

Comment: @windrunn3r.1990 Thanks! This solved my problem.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I understand that. This application is just for some tests and I'm trying to simulate the cases.

Comment: @LiuGarry I don't see how that's a reason to do any of the things I mentioned in my comment.  They're only going to cause problems and be more work, whether it's a small test or a production application.